# InnoSetup поиск расположения файла sqlcmd.exe

Tags: inno-setup

Необходимо в InnoSetup найти месторасположение файла sqlcmd.exe, полный путь к файлу, какую функцию использовать

Answer (score 2):

Как обычно, посмотреть в реестре:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\ClientSetup\@Path
```

Для этого используются функции [RegValueExists](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_regvalueexists) и [RegQueryStringValue](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_regquerystringvalue).

```
if RegValueExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\ClientSetup', 'Path') then
begin
    RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\ClientSetup', 'Path', FolderPath);
end
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду пробовать

Comment: Нет, при вытяжке из этой ветки реестра - не получаем расположение файла для 10 и 8.1 64 разрядных

Answer (score 0):

**MaLS** забыл учесть что бывают х64 системы, в которых существует отдельная копия реестра для 32х-битных приложений, каковым и является ваш инсталлятор.
Делайте так:

```
if IsWin64 then
  RegQueryStringValue(HKLM64, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\ClientSetup', 'Path', sqlcmdPath)
else
  RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\ClientSetup', 'Path', sqlcmdPath);
```